# Runtime.exec freezes when invoking ant script that contain hbm2ddl task?

Tags: java, ant, process

To launch an ant script I use the `exec` method of the class `java.lang.Runtime` as follows:

> Process process = Runtime.getRuntime (). Exec (JAVA_HOME ANT_HOME -jar
>   / lib / ant-launcher.jar-BuildFile file.xml);

This method, despite its apparent simplicity, but it poses several problems and is described in the javadoc as follows:

> Because Some native platforms Provide only limited buffer size for
>   standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input
>   stream or read the output stream of the subprocess May cause the
>   subprocess to block, and Even deadlock.

To solve this problem I referred to the following article:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1
This method worked for unemachine (64-bit Windows 7, Core 2 Quad Q9400 @ 2,66 GHz 2.67 GHz, 4GB)
But when I used another machine (XP SP3, Core 2 Duo 2.99 GHz @ 3 GHz, 3.21 GB memory), the process hangs at generating the data schema and the console remains desperately silent after posted the following message:

> [hibernatetool] Executing Hibernate Tool with a JPA Configuration
>   Warning: Reference not compilation.classpath.id HAS-been set at
>   runtime, goal WAS DURING found build file parsing, Attempting to
>   resolve. Future versions of Ant May support  referencing ids Defined
>   in non-executed targets.
>
> [Hibernatetool] 1. Task: hbm2ddl (Generates database schema).

Are you faced with a problem like this? Do you have a solution for me?
I am open to any solution.
Note: my ant script looks like this:

```
<project>
..
  <target name="create-jpa-schema">
      <tstamp>
         <format property="timestamp.for.sql" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss" />
      </ Tstamp>
      <hibernatetool destdir="${build.sql.dir}">
         <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath.id" />
            <pathelement path="${model.jar}" />
         </ Classpath>

         <jpaconfiguration persistenceunit="studio-pu" />
         <! - Export schema to SQL database and run it Against ->
         <Hbm2ddl drop = "false" update = "true" create = "true" export = "true" outputfilename = "$ {schema_ timestamp.for.sql}. Sql" delimiter = "" format = "true" haltOnError = "true "/>
      </ Hibernatetool>
   </ Target>
..
</ Project>
```

**EDIT:**
Code that execute runtime.exec:

```
public static int executeCommand(
      String cmd,
      File directory) throws IOException, InterruptedException
   {
      Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, directory);
      StreamReader outputStreamReader = new StreamReader(
         process.getInputStream(),
         "OUTPUT");
      StreamReader errorStreamReader = new StreamReader(process.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");
      final Thread outputThreadReader = new Thread(outputStreamReader);
      final Thread errorThreadReader = new Thread(errorStreamReader);

      outputThreadReader.start();
      errorThreadReader.start();

      int exitCode = process.waitFor();
      System.out.println("exit code:" + exitCode);
      return exitCode;

   }
```

StreamReader.java

```
public class StreamReader implements Runnable
{
   InputStream is;

   OutputStream os;

   String type;   

   StreamReader(InputStream is, String type)
   {
      this.is = is;
      this.type = type;
   }

   StreamReader(InputStream is, OutputStream os, String type)
   {
      this.is = is;
      this.os = os;
      this.type = type;
   }

   @Override
   public void run()
   {
      try
      {
         PrintWriter pw = null;

         if (os != null)
            pw = new PrintWriter(os);

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
               if (pw != null)
               {
                  pw.println(line);
                  pw.flush();
               }
               else
                  System.out.println(type + ">" + line);
               if(progressListener!=null)
               progressListener.onUpdate(line);
            }

      }
      catch (IOException ioe)
      {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the ant task on the command line on both machines? Does it do the same thing? If so, the problem will not be due to `Runtime.exec()`

Comment: the script run normally on the command line

Comment: Are you using the StreamGobbler as per the javaworld article? Or are you outputting the command line's stdout to your stdout?

Comment: im using a StreamGobler that outputting in the standard stdout

Comment: Can you post your code that uses Runtime.exec(), as well as the code that handles the child process stdout and stderr? This is most likely where the problem is.

Comment: I just edit the question and I included the code that you asked

Comment: The code looks fine to me. It's also puzzling that it works on one machine but not another. Is there a difference in JVM version, or perhaps installed libraries/databases that could possibly make it hang?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is a possibility but have you considered invoking ant programmatically, instead of launching a new process?

According to [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0502_gawor/0502_gawor.html), you should be able to do the following in a new thread instead of spawing a process:

```
File buildFile = new File("build.xml");
Project p = new Project();
p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
p.init();
ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
helper.parse(p, buildFile);
p.executeTarget(p.getDefaultTarget());
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `System.out.println()` before and after `readLine()` in StreamReader. Find out whether it is still actively reading when the console hangs or whether the thread exited prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Is the schema that you are exporting especially large? Will it produce a lot of output?

There is a 'console' attribute on the ant task `hbm2ddl` which, if `console="true"`, copies the ddl to `System.out.println()`, which may be causing your problem. It may be messing up the buffering on your XP box.

The default is console="true". Try with console="false".

```
<Hbm2ddl console="false" drop = "false" update = "true" create = "true" export = "true" outputfilename = "$ {schema_ timestamp.for.sql}. Sql" delimiter = "" format = "true" haltOnError = "true "/>
```

For more information, see [Hbm2ddl Ant task code](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/hibernate/trunk/HibernateExt/tools/src/java/org/hibernate/tool/ant/Hbm2DDLExporterTask.java)